# Is it possible to previously load a UIViewController in iOs

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, camera, loading

in my iPhone application, i am using Unifeye mobileviewcontroller classes including EAGLView and metaio sdk. When I load this viewcontroller camera view will be activated along with this some of the metaio class functions also get called. In effect, it is taking so much of time to load the view controller. And also if I try to navigate to another view from Unifeye viewcontroller and coming back for sometimes, the app is crashing. 
So, I just wondering like, is there any way to load the viewcontroller in the background or at the beginning when the app opens. I am not sure. Please share your ideas if there is any possible to ways to make the loading quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the camera is presented once the controller is loaded? Your controller is loaded normally, but it takes time to launch the camera. Here is where you get the delay. And you cannot fasten the load of the imagePickerController. Instead, you could present the camera in viewDidAppear, so the user will first see your controller, then the delay then the camera.

Comment: Now i am calling the camera loading function from viewwillappear method with a delay. But still taking time to load the camera.

Comment: That's it, the view did not appear yet, and you already try presenting the camera: as a result, the user still see the previous view controller until the capera is presented. And why using performSelectorAfterDelay in viewWillAppear, if you can do it normally in viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much work you're doing in the init method of your viewcontroller, you could at least show an activity indicator while the viewcontroller is initializing. To do that asynchronously you can use code like that:

```
- (IBAction)onStartPushed:(id)sender
{
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    // initialize the viewcontroller with a little delay, so that the UI displays the changes made above
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        ARViewController* theViewController = [[ARViewController alloc] init];

        // present the viewcontroller
        [self presentModalViewController:theViewController animated:YES];

        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
}
```

Within your viewcontroller you can do the same thing if you e.g. want to load big 3D models or tracking configurations that would block the main thread.